# Как с помощью нативного NodeJS-модуля "http" получить полный URL, на который был отправлен запрос?

Tags: node.js, http

Допустим, с REST-клиента отправили запрос `http://localhost:1337/`.
Как с помощью функционала нативного пакета `http` получить это значение?

Нигде в объекте запроса `request` я этого значения не нашел.
В частности, его нет в автоматически генерируемых заголовках:

```json
{
  "host": "localhost:1337",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "accept": "application/json",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Поскольку в этом вопросе речь идёт о решении задачи нативными средствами, то попрошу не рекомендовать мне фреймворки типа `express`.

Comment: `Request.path`  .

Comment: @Дмытрык, благодарю Вас за комментарий. Вы под Request имеете ввиду `HTTP.IncomingMessage`? Если да, то свойства `path` у `HTTP.IncomingMessage` нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:
`req.headers.host` - вернет вам хост
`req.url` - вернет вам оставшийся путь

```
const http = require('http');

let server = new http.Server(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.url)
    console.log(req.headers)

});

server.listen(8000, 'localhost');
```

Comment: соотвественно дальше объединить эти две строки

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! А возможен ли случай, когда `req.headers.host` имеет значение `undefined`?

Comment: Не сталкивалась с таким, если честно

Comment: К сожалению, мою правку отклонили. Пожалуйста, замените 5-ую строку на эти две: `console.log(req.headers.host); console.log(`http://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`)`.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, то так:

```
const http = require('http')

http.createServer(request => {
  console.log(request.url)
}).listen(8080)
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. К сожалению, не так: "request.url" включает в себя только путь, то есть при бросании запроса на `http://localhost:3000/foo/bar` , `request.url` будет `/foo/bar`.